# Node icon in a jsTree tree with font-awesome

Tags: xml, xslt, jstree, font-awesome

I have a tree structure using jsTree, like this:

```
<div id="jstree">
        <ul>
           <li>Root 1
             <li> Child 1</li>  
           </li>   
        </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to put icons of [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) for the roots and children. [Here](http://www.jstree.com/docs/html) is explained how to do it with bootstrap, below and example:

```
 <li data-jstree='{"icon":"glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"}'>Child</li>
```

I tried by doing this:

```
<li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-user fa-2x"}'>
```

and this is the error that the browser tells me:

> Invalid character (:) in expression "icon":"fa fa-user fa-2x"

I should also mention that I am using XML and XSL.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have `<li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-user fa-2x"}'>` literally in XSLT code then I think you want `<li data-jstree='{{"icon":"fa fa-user fa-2x"}}'>` instead to prevent the XSLT engine from processing the attribute value as an attribute value template.

Comment: How do we achieve this if we use JSON data for tree and not an HTML markup?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following design:

```
<div id="jstree">
<ul>
  <li data-jstree='{"opened":true,"icon":"fa fa-folder-open"}'>Accounts
    <ul>
      <li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-folder"}'>Account 1
      <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-file"}'>File 1</li> 
        <li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-file"}'>File 2</li> 
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-folder"}'>Account 2
      <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-file"}'>File 1</li> 
        <li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-file"}'>File 2</li> 
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And you change how it looks once the folder is opened or closed:

```js
// bind customize icon change function in jsTree open_node event. 
$('#jstree').on('open_node.jstree', function(e, data){
    var icon = $('#' + data.node.id).find('i.jstree-icon.jstree-themeicon').first();
    icon.removeClass('fa-folder').addClass('fa-folder-open');
});

// bind customize icon change function in jsTree close_node event. 
$('#jstree').on('close_node.jstree', function(e, data){
    var icon = $('#' + data.node.id).find('i.jstree-icon.jstree-themeicon').first();
    icon.removeClass('fa-folder-open').addClass('fa-folder');
});
```

Comment: but for me, although I use a json-stream

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the class you want to use with FA after the tree is loaded and when a node is open like this:

```
$('#my-tree').jstree({
    // --
    // your options 
    // --
}).on('open_node.jstree', function(e, data){
    $(".jstree-icon.jstree-themeicon").removeClass("jstree-icon jstree-themeicon").addClass("fa fa-users");
}).on('loaded.jstree', function(e, data) {
     $(".jstree-icon.jstree-themeicon").removeClass("jstree-icon jstree-themeicon").addClass("fa fa-users");
});
```